Бот не может изменить свое сообщение!
from aiogram import F, Router
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext

import source.moduls.keyboards.auth.buttons as kb

auth_callback = Router()


class Auth_login_password(StatesGroup):
    login = State()
    password = State()


@auth_callback.callback_query(F.data == "auth_login_password")
async def auth_login(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Auth_login_password.login)
    await callback.answer("")
    await callback.message.edit_text(text="Отправь мне свой логин от платформы Сетевой Город!")


@auth_callback.message(Auth_login_password.login)
async def auth_password_input(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(login=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Auth_login_password.password)

    await message.edit_text(text="Отправь мне свой пароль от платформы Сетевой Город!")


@auth_callback.message(Auth_login_password.password)
async def auth_password(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(password=message.text)

    data = await state.get_data()

    await message.edit_text(text=f"Твой логин: {data['login']} \nТвой Пароль: {data['password']}")

    await state.clear()```


В чем суть, я хочу что бы после каждого введенного ответа пользователем, бот редактировал свое предыдущее сообщение на новое. Но в консоли вылазит ошибка:
Telegram server says - Bad Request: message cant be edited


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Но вместо «своего предыдущего сообщения» вы почему-то пытаетесь редактировать сообщение присланное пользователем

@andreymal А как тогда  редактировать  сообщение бота?
